# Best Kovetz Shitos Kamai

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

I'm looking to buy a Kovetz Shitos Kamai. Does anyone have any recommendations?

As far as I'm aware, no two editions are too different from one another, so I guess the deciding factors would be quality of paper/print, size, price, and mareh mekomos inserted into the text.

Comment: Judaicaplaza has some: https://judaicaplaza.com/products/13709188?variant=41549576700103 Can't view the pages unfortunately.

Comment: You mean like a kovetz meforshim with the rishonim?